# how to display ffmpeg error output

Tags: php, cron, ffmpeg

I am executing certain code through ffmpeg to encode avi files to flv. My ffmpeg code is correct and is working fine, but when some error occurs (suppose it is a corrupted avi file, ffmpeg will not encode it), so i want to know what the error is. Here is a sample code:

```
$v_cmd=" some code to transcode";
exec($v_cmd,$v_output,$v_status);
if($v_status == 0)
{
echo "Success!";
}
else 
{
echo "ERROR: ".$v_output;
}
```

But this $v_output is just showing up as `ERROR: Array` ... i tried

```
echo "ERROR: ".implode($v_output);
```

but it was blank... how can i get the error message that ffmpeg gave so that i can understand what went wrong. This is a php cron script and it is not run in command line manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In POSIX-compliant systems and applications, errors will be sent to STDERR, not STDOUT. `exec` will only populate the `$output` argument with STDOUT:

```
exec("foo", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Displays:

```
array(0) {
}
```

You have to redirect STDERR to STDOUT if you want this to work. Per example, on *nix:

```
exec("foo 2>&1", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Will display:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "sh: foo: not found"
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. the `2>&1` helped. I have modified my code to generate the error based on the var_dump output.